# Failed to build project, libstlport_shared.so not found

Tags: android-ndk

I got this error while I'm trying to build my project using NDK

```
failed can not load library "libstlport_shared.so"
  needed by libpjsipjni.so;
  caused by load_library(linker.cpp:746)
                                :library"libstlport_shared.so" not found despite
```

During the build I can  see one line : `[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libstlport_shared.so => ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libstlport_shared.so`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to load it manually, like below :

```
 static{
    System.loadLibrary("stlport_shared");
    System.loadLibrary("pjsipjni");
 }
```

Good Luck.